# Get the box index of an item that is placed in one of series of boxes that increase in size?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My english fails me here as I don't know how better to call it then whats in the title.

Basically the boxes have ranges like this

[1] [2-3] [4-6] [7-10] and so on with each box being 1 unit bigger then the last one.

Then I have a number, say 4. I need to find out mathematically which box its in (in this instance its in box 3). How could I do that?

Also I have no idea how to tag this.

Comment: What do you mean by find out mathematically? Are you looking for a formula?

Comment: Shouldn't your last box be $[7-10]$ to avoid overlap with the earlier one?

Comment: oops, that was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your last box should be $[7-10]$, the upper limits of your boxes are the triangular numbers.  To find which box a number $x$ is in, compute $n=\frac 12(\sqrt {1+8x}-1)$ as shown in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number#Triangular_roots_and_tests_for_triangular_numbers) and round up